# Is it possible to use misty step to get in-between two characters?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, fighter

I'm currently playing an Eldritch Knight and I'd like to be able to use *misty step* to get in between an enemy and a PC.  I do have *lightning lure*, but the range on *misty step* is better and I'd much rather take the damage then them.

The handbook says "unoccupied space you can see" so I'd imagine that two people in a melee (especially a caster not using a weapon) would have at least five feet between them.  I am asking if that will work before trying to plan around that strategy in battle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### There isn't any unoccupied space between creatures in melee

Each medium and small creature is assumed to occupy 5 feet of space in combat. This is the area within which they move and swing weapons and can't be willingly occupied by another creature at the end of that creature's turn.

Creatures who have a 5 foot reach are toe-to-toe when in melee - there isn't space between them for you to *Misty Step* into. If they have a 10 foot or longer reach then there might be such a space but you being between them would not stop them attacking each other in such circumstances.

Comment: I'd say it depends on whether you're playing grid-based or "theater of the mind". If the former, then I agree with Dale M. If the latter, then I say go for it; in armed combat, there's plenty of room for a medium sized creature to intervene. But, yeah, you'd have to shove the enemy or grapple them or use a small weapon on them, because you wouldn't have enough room to swing a large weapon. My groups play more in the latter style, or a bit of a hybrid when I DM, because I like to have an idea of where everyone is, generally; and I'm pretty sure we would all agree to allow this.